# Download whole folder from Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

How do I down load a whole folder from my Ubuntu One account that is up loaded regularly from my computer.

I did a fresh install to Ubuntu 12.04 and need to reinstall my Thunderbird and other file.

Thanks, Bob.

Answer (score 1):

If you created additional synchronised folders on your first computer, you can synchronise them to the second computer using the control panel.

First choose `Ubuntu One` from the messaging menu (or search for it in the dash), and then check the `Sync Locally?` check box next to the folders you are interested in:

[image: Ubuntu One control panel]

The folder should begin downloading from the cloud immediately.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect again to your Ubuntu One account, the files that were uploaded before, will be automatically downloaded to your computer. This is the job of Ubuntu One: synchronize all the devices that are connected to the same account. So if you did a fresh install, simply connect to your Ubuntu One account.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would over write the files that were already uploaded with the fresh install files which contained nothing and my stored information would be lost. Not the case?

Comment: Is there a way to download a folder to my hard drive though?

Comment: As far as I know if Ubuntu one finds differences in the files, it creates a copy with the extension .u1conflict. Then you can choose which one to keep. After this, the regular synchronization is enabled. But I have no direct experience of this.

Comment: If you have a new install it's important to NOT copy over an old ~/.local/share/ubuntuone folder. That will result in Ubuntu One deleting the local files when it sees a previously populated local cache (~/.local/share/ubuntuone) and empty folders. The client will think you meant to delete the files in that case.